# Iterate through SelectList in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I am creating a select list;

```
    public string Ajax_GetUnusedDCList(Guid storeId)
    {
        DataRepository.Store thisStore = repo.Where(x => x.id == storeId).SingleOrDefault();
        SelectList list = thisStore.GetStoreUnusedDCList("Store");

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(list);
    }
```

Then in my jQuery I try to step through each item and alert out values at this point;

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Stores/Ajax_GetUnusedDCList",
  type: 'POST',
  data: { storeId: '041F0D0E-5AD3-4817-9604-3FD81F08BA9B' },
  success: function (data) {
    $(data).each(function (index, val) {
      alert(val.Text);
    });
  }
});
```

However I get errors like;

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized
>   expression: [{"Selected":false,"Text":"9321","Value":null}]
>
> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'length' is null or not an object
>
> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object
>
> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'matches' is null or not an object

All I want to do is return a SelectList and populate a drop down.

Comment: You should look at the returned `data` and see what it really is.

Comment: If you look at the first error it appears to be [{"Selected":false,"Text":"9321","Value":null}] which looks ok I think

Comment: Use `each` in a different format. Don't try and make jQuery objects out of your data. `$.each(data, function(i,v){...});`

Comment: Is the returned data a single string or has it been parsed into javascript.  Perhaps you need to tell the ajax() function that the returned data is JSON.

Comment: $.each(data... give this error.  Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Answer (score 1):

I think u can send the SelectList without serializing So that u can acess on the client side with ur function itself.
as

```
return Json(listObj,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got data as a string, so first need to convert data into json object.

Try below code to convert string to json in client side.

```
success: function (data) {
    var json = (typeof data) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data+ ')') : data;
    $(json).each(function (index, val) {
         alert(val.Text);
    });   }
```

This will help to solve your issue.